# Parse SignUpViewController signUpViewControllerShouldSignBeginSignUp delegate function is not being called

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I am writing a Parse app and using the Parse LoginViewController and SignUpViewController. I have been using the SubclassConfigViewController as a model from their LoginAndSignUp demo. As they talk about in their documentation, I want to check the username and password for various things before the signUp commences.  This should take place in the delegate function "signUpViewControllerShouldSignBeginSignUp"
But, it is not being called and the app signs up anybody.  It checks only that at the email is in a valid format and that a user name exists. I have put a println (Swift) at the beginning of the function.  It never prints.
What can I do to force this function to run?
The "loginViewControllerShouldLogInUser" runs as expected.

Here is my code:

```
class LoginConfigViewController: UIViewController, PFLogInViewControllerDelegate, PFSignUpViewControllerDelegate
{

    var loginViewController: LoginViewController! = LoginViewController()
    var signUpViewController: SignUpViewController! = SignUpViewController()

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
    {

        if (PFUser.currentUser() == nil)
        {

            loginViewController.delegate = self
            loginViewController.fields = PFLogInFields.UsernameAndPassword |  PFLogInFields.LogInButton | PFLogInFields.SignUpButton | PFLogInFields.DismissButton

            //signUpViewController.delegate = self;
            signUpViewController.fields = PFSignUpFields.Default | PFSignUpFields.Additional | PFSignUpFields.DismissButton
            loginViewController.signUpController = signUpViewController;
            loginViewController.signUpController?.delegate = self

            self.presentViewController(self.loginViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
        }
        else
        {
            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
        }

    }

    // MARK: - PFLogInViewControllerDelegate


    func logInViewController(logInController: PFLogInViewController!, shouldLogInUser user: PFUser!, password: String!) -> Bool {
        println("shouldLogIn...")

        return true
    }

    func logInViewController(logInController: PFLogInViewController, shouldBeginLogInWithUsername username: String, password: String) -> Bool {
        println("should login in \(username)")

        return true
    }

    @IBAction func logInViewController(logInController: PFLogInViewController, didLogInUser user: PFUser) {
        println("didLogInUser \(user.username)")
        self.loginViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)

    }

    // Sent to the delegate when the log in screen is dismissed.
    func logInViewControllerDidCancelLogin(logInController: PFLogInViewController!) {
        println("User dismissed the logInViewController")
        self.loginViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
    }



    // MARK: - PFSignUpViewControllerDelegate

    // Sent to the delegate to determine whether the sign up request should be submitted to the server.
    func signUpViewControllerShouldBeginSignUp(signUpViewController: PFSignUpViewController!, info: NSDictionary) -> Bool {
        println("signUpViewController::shouldBeginSignUp")

        return true
    }

    // Sent to the delegate when a PFUser is signed up.
    func signUpViewController(signUpViewController: PFSignUpViewController, didSignUpUser user: PFUser) {
        println("didSignUpUser \(user.username)")
        user.removeObjectForKey("additional")
        self.signUpViewController.stopAI()
        self.signUpViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
        self.loginViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)


    }


    // Sent to the delegate when the sign up attempt fails.
    func signUpViewController(signUpViewController: PFSignUpViewController!, didFailtoSignUpWithError error: NSError) {
        println("Failed to sign up...")
    }

    // Sent to the delegate when the sign up screen is dismissed.
    func signUpViewControllerDidCancelSignUp(signUpViewController: PFSignUpViewController) {
        println("User dismissed the signUpViewController")
        signUpViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
    }

    //MARK: - ()
    func logOutButtonTapAction(sender: AnyObject) {
        PFUser.logOut()
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The logincontroller has a property which is called `signUpController` which is the signupcontroller called by the logincontroller.

So if you want to check what the user did (signing up or canceling or something) you need to set the delegate of the logincontroller's signupcontroller by calling this:

```
loginViewController.signUpController?.delegate = self
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for the tip.  I have set that now.  I have no doubt it needed it. But, the "shouldBeginSignUp" function is still not being called.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: In addition  to adding:  " loginViewController.signUpController?.delegate = self "   I removed : " signUpViewController.delegate = self "   But that still didn't help.  shouldBeginSignUp  is still not being called.

Comment: @epaus Can you give me your new code (edit your question)?
On my tested example this works

Comment: Thanks RaVeN.  I make the changes to reflect commenting out : signUpViewController.delegate = self  and adding :  loginViewController.signUpController?.delegate = self    Could there be something else that's different?

Comment: loginViewController.signUpController = signUpViewController; delete this column, should work fine

Comment: When I take out "loginViewController.signUpController = signUpViewController",  it no longer calls my signUpViewController that I configured.  Instead, it calls the Parse default signUpController.  But I tried it anyway, and it still didn't call : signUpViewControllerShouldBeginSignUp(signUpViewController: PFSignUpViewController!, info: NSDictionary) -> Bool

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem, the default parse Login and signup controllers would not act on their assigned methods. After hours and hours of trouble shooting and not being able to find an answer, Ended up not using the default parse UI and creating my own and it worked fine and talked to parse just fine. Here is the [Youtube Video](https://youtu.be/7sL47vpWTMU) that shows you the code you need for a custom login. For some reason or another their methods just won't call and its frustrating. Once the user logged in I just used a segue to my Home view Controller.

```
 self.actInd.startAnimating()
  PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(username, password: password, block: { (user, NSError) -> Void in

    self.actInd.stopAnimating()

    if ((user) != nil) {

      println("success user logged in")

      self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toHome", sender: self)
    }else {

      var alert: UIAlertView = UIAlertView(title: "error", message: "You are logged in already", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Ok")
      alert.show()
    }
```

Hope that helps.
best of luck!

Comment: Hey thanks.  I was already doing that.  But while looking at your code, I realized I could do the stuff that I wanted to do by setting a target for the signUpButton.  I wanted to confirm the password matched the confirmation password, and I could do that in the target I set for the signUpButton.  For some reason, I felt like that should be done in shouldBeginSignUp, which was probably their intention.  But as you say, their methods aren't getting called.  Thank you for your input.  It's reassuring to know it's not just me having this problem with these functions getting not called.  Thanks.

Comment: Well shucks.  I was trying to avoid writing the code for signUp like you did and just add a target to the already existing signUpButton.  But, it turns out that I can't control (i.e. prevent) the signup that way, so I'll do what you did, which is create your own signupButton in your SignUpViewController and add an action for it...spelling out exactly the signup code.  How annoying.  Why can't the the functions just work like they are supposed to.  Again thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue , try this :

```
let logInController = LogInViewController()
let signUpController = SignUpViewController()
logInController.delegate = self
signUpController.delegate = self
logInController.signUpController = signUpController
```